# laravel create, delete, update hasMany with many fields

Tags: php, laravel, has-many

I'm new to laravel. I have 2 table

```
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function clientmoreinfo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Moreinfoclient');
    }
}

class Moreinfoclient extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'clients_additionalfield';
    protected $fillable = ['client_id', 'nameinput', 'valueinput'];

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
}
```

and i need to be able to add many additional fields at once as seen here:
[image]

this is how I add any number of entries, and more importantly, how do I update or remove them later?

thank you all in advance !